# Adding test cases to list in Python

Tags: python, append

I have a number of tests cases each defined in separate python files.

```
<file1.py>
class tc(testcase.tc):
     ....

<file2.py>
class tc(testcase.tc):
     ....
```

My main processing loop in RunTests.py has the following

```
class TestTable(wx.grid.PyGridTableBase):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.grid.PyGridTableBase.__init__(self)
        self.cols = "Execute Number Name Status".split()
        self.cases = []
        package = tests
        prefix = package.__name__ + "."
        for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__, prefix):
          if 'tests.testcase' != modname:          # skip the testcase.py file/module
              print modname
              module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
              print module.tc()
              self.cases.append( module.tc() )
```

I end up getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute tc.  My prints show the test case and tc instance

test.xxx

Not sure why....

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that you have there also other files, that don't contain `tc` class. Maybe it'll be enough just to add test `if hasattr(module, 'tc')` before `self.cases.append`.